# Cron : How to delete directory via cron

Tags: 14.04, server, cron

I have allready installed cron and here it is

> 1 0 * * * rm -R /path/to/my/folder/$(date +'%Y-%m-%d'
>   -d "yesterday")

I want to delete every day folder with "Yesterday name" LIKE "2014-12-14"

Here is my ubuntu /var/log/syslog when I execute "grep CRON" command

> Dec 16 00:01:01 {SERVERNAME} CRON[21031]: (root) CMD (rm -R
>   /path/to/my/folder/$(date +') Dec 16 00:01:01 {SERVERNAME} CRON[21030]:
>   (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manpage (`man 5 crontab`) says:

> The entire command portion of the line, up  to  a  newline  or  % 
>   character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in
>   the  SHELL variable of the crontab file.  Percent-signs (%) in the 
>   command,  unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into
>   newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent  to
>   the  command  as  standard  input.

So you have to replace every `%` in your date format with `\%`:

```
1 0 * * * rm -R /path/to/my/folder/$(date +'\%Y-\%m-\%d' -d "yesterday")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command

`find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 0 -ctime +1 -exec rm -fr {} +`

i.e

`1 0 * * * find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 0 -ctime +1 -exec rm -fr {} +`

[Credit Goes Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398407/how-to-delete-folders-that-are-older-than-a-day-cron-job)